# Conditionally modifying within list of dataframes

Tags: r, optimization, subset, lapply

I have been playing with the `WHO` package that contains a great amount of data. A good thing is that the `get_data` function allows to pull several tables into a list of data.frames (using `lapply`)

```
### Socio-Economic indicators

    # health expenditure, GDP per capita, Literacy Rate, 
      Fertility Rate, Pop under 1 USD, Population,

socio_econ <- c("WHS7_143", "WHS9_93", "WHS9_85", "WHS9_95", 'WHS9_90', 'WHS9_86')

SECON <- lapply(socio_econ, function(t) get_data(t))
```

The ultimate goal is to bind the data.frames, possibly using `bind_rows` function from `dplyr`. One problem is that each of the data.frames comes with the response variable called `'value'` in a different order (Hence it is not possible to subset the same number of column within each data frame in the list). Similar problem arises with the class of the columns, for example `'year'`. Basically, each modification would need to conditionally find the particular columns by name and assign new values.

My solution has been to use a for loop but I think there must be a cleaner way using lapply type functions. Here's to change the names and year class.

```
for (i in 1:length(socio_econ)){

  names(SECON[[i]])[which(names(SECON[[i]])=='value')] <- socio_econ[i]
  SECON[[i]]$year <- as.character(SECON[[i]]$year)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` in a `lapply` call to change the class of the "year" and "value" colums to numeric. Since the data.frames in the list have a different number of columns, I would suggest a `full_join` using `Reduce`.

```
library(dplyr)
SECON <-lapply(SECON, function(df) mutate_at(df, .cols = c("year","value"), as.numeric))
output <- Reduce(full_join, SECON)
```

This gives me an output object of dimension 14169x8. 14169 corresponds to the total number of lines in all list elements.

Comment: This seems to work for me, +1 for mutate_at with multiple columns. I didn't realize before the question that the data was correctly formatted, the value column has spaces between numbers and will be coerced to NA. Also, merging by value column is better for plots but then 'gho' variable explains real life variables in a very cumbersome way (only requires some cleaning actually)

Comment: I was microbenchmarking it and it seems slower than my for loop + bind_rows. From console output and from the autoplot, seems that Reduce(full_join...) is what takes more than anything, in the ~100 ms scale while the everything else happens in 1 ms scale

Comment: Yeah, I imagine it must take more time. I put that because `bind_rows` would probably fail because you have 7 columns in some elements of the lsit and 8 in others.

Comment: bind_rows give me an 14169x8 data.frame with your structure. Missing values are NA and it's in the nanoscale I think we have a winner

Answer (score 0):

You could nest a couple of functions like:

```
f.bind <- function(x){

  f.get <- function(x){
      x %>% 
          dplyr::select(region, year, value)
  } 

  x = lapply(c, f.get)
  do.call(rbind,(x))
}
```

The inner function is just wrapping a small dplyr select function and the outer function is applying the inner and binding all of the results.